# Symfony ERROR Syntax error or access violation

Tags: symfony

I try to follow the tutorial on the symfony site but when I execute the command php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate an error appears:

> An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE app_users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL, is_active TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_C2502824F85E0677 (username), UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_C2502824E7927C74 (email), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET
>     utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Do you have any idea where this might come from? Thank you

Comment: Ok thx sorry for my post.

Comment: just replace in your all entities 191 where string length greater than 191. for example: In your entity app_users you have email VARCHAR(254)

Comment: or use UTF8 instead of UTF8mb4